# Gmap4rails: infowindow render action from different controller

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps

I have a home.html.erb file where I am displaying markers. Markers correspond to a new sport created by a user. When the marker is clicked I want to display the sport information (along with other values).
In the main controller I have associated the show partial with the markers and pass the required locales.

```
 @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@game) do |game, marker|
    marker.lat game.latitude
    marker.lng game.longitude
    marker.infowindow render_to_string(:partial => 'games/show', :layout => false, :locals => { :@game => @game })   
    end
  end
```

In the _show.html.erb file, I am trying the display the sport, associated with game.

```
<div class="row">
  <aside class="span4">
    <section>
        <p>
          <strong>Sport:</strong> 
            <%= @game.sport %>
        </p>
    </section>
  </aside>
</div>
```

I am getting the following error. 
undefined method `sport' for #.

How can I display the parameters in @game in the infowindow.

Regards
Hari

Comment: I found the mistake. It should be :locals => {:@game => game}